# Is `store.find` function different to `store.findRecord` function on Ember JS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

There are two similar functions on Ember JS service "store".
In this example they work alike.

`find` function

```js
  @service store;

  async model(params) {
    return this.store.find('rental', params.rental_id);
  }
```

`findRecord` function

```js
  @service store;

  async model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('rental', params.rental_id);
  }
```

Are they different? Or just an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`store.find` is private and deprecated. `store.findRecord` is the right method to find specific records by id.

You can see more details here.

[store.find](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/35ff11dd76dc15b2df3be6e672e9753c70dc0e0f/packages/store/src/-private/store-service.ts#L692)

```
// The default `model` hook in Route calls `find(modelName, id)`,
// that's why we have to keep this method around even though `findRecord` is
// the public way to get a record by modelName and id.
```